# XSLT exclude one specific node from Select

Tags: xslt, select, apply-templates

I've looked high and low for an answer to this, and tried *hundreds* of permutations, but nothing at all has worked.

I'm trying to process all the nodes of a simple XML document EXCEPT for the very first `<title>` node. Basically, I'm trying to find an xslt instruction that accomplishes the exact INVERSE of

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/topic/title"/>
```

Here is my source XML:

```
<topic>
    <title>Name of the Document</title>
    <p>Document body</p>
    <topic>
        <title>First Document Subtopic</title>
        <p>Body text for first document subtopic</p>
    </topic>
    <p>Body text continued for document</p>
    <topic>
        <title>Second Document Subtopic</title>
        <p>Body text for document subtopic</p>
        <topic>
            <title>First Document Sub-subtopic</title>
            <p>Body text for first document sub-subtopic</p>
        </topic>
    </topic>
    <p>Body text continued a second time for document</p>
</topic>
```

and here is my XSLT (with what I originally *thought* should work in the call to apply-templates):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <BOX>
            <TEXTFLOW>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(/topic/title)]"/>
            </TEXTFLOW>
        </BOX>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="topic">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <FORMAT>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </FORMAT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here's what I *want* to see (note the absence of the first `<title>` matter):

```
<BOX>
    <TEXTFLOW>
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <FORMAT>Document body</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
        <FORMAT>First Document Subtopic</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <FORMAT>Body text for first document subtopic</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <FORMAT>Body text continued for document</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
        <FORMAT>Second Document Subtopic</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <FORMAT>Body text for document subtopic</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
        <FORMAT>First Document Sub-subtopic</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <FORMAT>Body text for first document sub-subtopic</FORMAT>
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <FORMAT>Body text continued a second time for document</FORMAT>
    </TEXTFLOW>
</BOX>
```

What select expression can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can just use this XPath in your root template:

```
select=".//*[generate-id() != generate-id(/topic/title)]"
```

You'd need to change your template for `topic` to:

```
<xsl:template match="topic" />
```

The problem you're having is because your current select only specifies the immediate children that should be processed- from the root note (`/`), this is actually only the top level `topic` element. The `.//*` in the XPath above specifies all descendants regardless of level, and the predicate explicitly excludes the first `/topic/title` element.

You need to make sure your `topic` elements are NOT processing their children, as their children are already being processed by the select instruction in the root template.

Answer (score 6):

**As easy as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <BOX>
            <TEXTFLOW>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </TEXTFLOW>
        </BOX>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/topic/title"/>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <FORMAT>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </FORMAT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<topic>
    <title>Name of the Document</title>
    <p>Document body</p>
    <topic>
        <title>First Document Subtopic</title>
        <p>Body text for first document subtopic</p>
    </topic>
    <p>Body text continued for document</p>
    <topic>
        <title>Second Document Subtopic</title>
        <p>Body text for document subtopic</p>
        <topic>
            <title>First Document Sub-subtopic</title>
            <p>Body text for first document sub-subtopic</p>
        </topic>
    </topic>
    <p>Body text continued a second time for document</p>
</topic>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<BOX>
   <TEXTFLOW>
      <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
      <FORMAT>Document body</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
      <FORMAT>First Document Subtopic</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
      <FORMAT>Body text for first document subtopic</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
      <FORMAT>Body text continued for document</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
      <FORMAT>Second Document Subtopic</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
      <FORMAT>Body text for document subtopic</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
      <FORMAT>First Document Sub-subtopic</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
      <FORMAT>Body text for first document sub-subtopic</FORMAT>
      <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
      <FORMAT>Body text continued a second time for document</FORMAT>
   </TEXTFLOW>
</BOX>
```

**Explanation**:

To exclude the wanted element(s) from processing, we use a template that matches them and has no body:

```
    <xsl:template match="/topic/title"/>
```

---

**II. Update**

The following alternative solution is not recommended, because it is example of "pull style" and is not so flexible, elegant and maintainable as the "push style" solution above, however the OP insists that he needs such inferior solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <BOX>
       <TEXTFLOW>
        <xsl:apply-templates
        select="*/*[not(self::title)]"/>
       </TEXTFLOW>
      </BOX>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <PARA STYLE="Title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <PARA STYLE="BodyText"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <FORMAT>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </FORMAT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), it again produces the wanted, correct result**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dimitre; I should further qualify the requirement, though: I do indeed need to process that node in another, separate, apply-templates call. So what I was looking for was one apply-templates with a select that matched the node in question, then a separate apply-templates with a select that matched everything OTHER than that node. I have a workaround that employs 'mode', but it's going to be a bit clumsy as I build this out... do you have a way to use select to exclude that node?

Comment: @Andy, Using modes is not clumsy and is a recommended way of treating a node in more than one way. Also, to ask a question and then to say, "Oh, I forgot this and this ... ", isn't something to recommend. Your question in its original form is fully answered. Please, *accept* the answer (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer) and ask a new, separate question, if you still think that using modes is clumsy.

Comment: Actually, my question quite clearly asked how I would accomplish the result with a Select expression, so while I appreciate your help, my original question is still unanswered, and I didn't really forget to mention anything relevant to it. For this particular use case, modes are a tricky play in the larger context (indeed it's the workaround I'm using now), and a well-crafted select would make it much more manageable. Can you (or someone) suggest a solution that uses Select?